# How to handle duplicate data of child table that belongs to 1 of 2 parent table has many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 tables called **Product** and **Category** with many-to-many relationship. And **Product** has a one-to-many relationship with **Images** table. I created a table **Product_Category** to link 2 table Product and Category together. My problem is when 1 product belongs to 1 category, it's just fine with 4 images of that product. But if 1 product belongs to 2 categories, i get 8 images instead of 4

[This is image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2OiK.png)
As you can see is's supposed to be _1 _2 _3 _4 instead _1 _1 _2 _2 ...

This is my entities class

**ProductEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "material")
    private String material;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="careId")
    private ProductCareEntity productCare;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ImageEntity> images;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProductCategoryEntity> productCategoryEntities;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderDetailEntity> orderDetailEntityList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductSizeQuantityEntity> productSizeQuantities;
```

**CategoryEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class CategoryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProductCategoryEntity> productCategories;
```

**ProductCategoryEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategoryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private ProductEntity product;
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need **ProductCategoryEntity** at all. All you need to do is to make a List of Category type in product and List of Product type in Category. like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "price")
private double price;

@Column(name = "material")
private String material;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="careId")
private ProductCareEntity productCare;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ImageEntity> images;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "ProductCategory", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
private List<Category> categories;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderDetailEntity> orderDetailEntityList;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductSizeQuantityEntity> productSizeQuantities;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class CategoryEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
@JoinTable(name = "ProductCategory")
private List<Product> products;
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, i'll try it. But you have any clue to solve my problem in the way i describe above? i appreciate it.